# Configure repository field on package.json on monorepo

Tags: node.js, git, shell, yarnpkg, lerna

## Situation

I have a monorepo created with `lerna` with 40-50 projects. Each has a `package.json` like this.

```
{
  "name": "@base-repo/add-class-methods",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

The folder structure is like this,

```
packages
├── absolute-url
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
├── add-class-methods
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
├── check-set-relative
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
├── crypto
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
```

If I push it to github, it will have a single github url, however I saw `babel` has 142 packages where each of them has a custom `repository` field in the `package.json`.

```
"repository": "https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-types"
```

I hope they are not setting this value manually for 142 packages. Same with my 40 small packages.

I understand I can manually set them in 3-4 minutes by the time I am writing this question. However this will get overwhelming when I try to do the same with a 150 package monorepo or in future.

## Problem

How can I set/update the repository field without opening each `package.json` file manually for 40 packages?

## What I tried

Manually set each as possible, but things quickly got boring and repeating considering I am a programmer. Then I googled the solution for around an hour. Finally I wrote the following script,

```
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const gitUrl = 'https://github.com/user';
const author = `Mr. Github User <user@example.com> (${gitUrl})`;
const basePath = '/utility-scripts/tree/master';
const baseRepo = gitUrl + basePath;

glob('packages/*/package.json', (err, files) => {
  for (const filePath of files) {
    const [parent, pkg] = filePath.split('/');
    const newData = {
      author,
      license: 'MIT',
      repository: `${baseRepo}/${parent}/${pkg}`,
    };
    const data = Object.assign(
      {},
      JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(filePath), 'utf-8')),
      newData,
    );
    fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(filePath), JSON.stringify(data, true, 2));
  }
});
```

Is there an easy way to deal with this? With any kind of `shell`, `git`, `yarn` or `npm` command?

Comment: I came looking for the same thing, so far it looks like a custom node script, ran manually is the way to go. It's true, there are no recommendations online what to do with "repository" and "homepage" fields in lerna's deeper level (not root) packages' `package.json`'s

Comment: Still did not find the solution. :D